# Adding pagination to inner join-ed laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am getting error on pagination

```
$writers = $writer::join('categories','categories.id','=','writers.category_id')
    ->where([['categories.category_name', '=', $category]])->paginate(1);
```

Can anyone tell how to paginate an inner join query.

This is the error message I'm getting:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from writers` inner join categories on categories.id = writers.category_id where (categories.category_name = Comic))

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Whats problem ?

Comment: `QueryException in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `writers` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `writers`.`category_id` where (`categories`.`category_name` = Comic))`

Comment: This is the whole error. But when I remove `->paginate();` query works perfectly

Comment: Added error message that OP had stated in comments to clearify the issue at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `GROUP_BY` clause on your query

```
$writers = Writer::join('categories','categories.id','=','writers.category_id')
   ->where('categories.category_name', '=', $category)
   ->groupBy('writers.id')
   ->paginate(1);
```

**UPDATE**

If you still get an error, check your `config/database.php`. Be sure that in mysql settings`strict = false`

**UPDATE 2**

strict mode works on mysql starting from 5.7. If you have mysql under 5.7, set `strict => false`. You can check this link for more information:

[Strict mode](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: This is me getting now

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'laravel5.writers.writer_name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `writers` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `writers`.`category_id` where (`categories`.`category_name` = Comics) group by `writers`.`id` limit 1 offset 0)

Comment: It works! Can you explain what it this `strict=false` ?

Comment: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2